# Security of locally stored cookies

Tags: security, cookies

Is a cookie secure if it is only stored locally on the client's browser and never sent over the internet to a server?

Edit - Im making an encrypted file service, the way it works is that the user has two passwords, one for logging into his account and another for encrypting and decrypting their files. Upon logging in they are presented with a window that asks them for their decryption password. This password is stored in a cookie on the user's browser. A encrypted list of files is sent from the server and javascript uses the cookie to decrypt it(and encrypt uploaded files once in the browser and then php encrypts it on the server). Is this a secure way of doing things or is their a better way? P.S. I do use an SSL but I'm trying to add more security

Comment: You might want to flesh out your question and ask it at security.stackexchange.com -- I don't think it's a very good fit here at SO.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist is so right. I would answer this question with 1-2 pages but, in short; use local storage feature of HTML5 for storing keys instead of cookie.

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is sent with every request. So if you set a cookie on the browser using a header:

```
Set-Cookie: Password=foo
```

Then even if an image is requested from your server:

```
<img src="/images/bar.jpg" />
```

the request will contain the cookie that was set:

```
Cookie: Password=foo
```

Instead, [HTML5 session storage is recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). Session storage is unique to each browser tab and is cleared when the user leaves the page. It can only be read via JavaScript and it is not sent automatically for every request.

Also, as you will have a password that is readable by a local attacker and because password based keys are only as secure as the password, it is recommended to use a JavaScript [PBFDF2](http://anandam.name/pbkdf2/) or [bcrypt implementation](https://github.com/nevins-b/javascript-bcrypt) in order to strengthen the key. This will make any encrypted objects harder to decrypt via a brute-force attack, as each password try will need to run through a hash function, slowing the attack considerably. This also means that the password won't be viewable in cleartext if the storage is viewed on the client. While this may be a moot point because if an attacker can read the encryption key even though it is hashed they can still decrypt the data, although if the user has reused their passwords on other systems it will not be able to be reverse-engineered for use there.